# Writing sql nested query into laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

The Query is:

```
SELECT * FROM startups where id IN (
     SELECT startups.id as id 
     FROM startups startups 
     INNER JOIN funds ON  startups.id=funds.startup_id 
     INNER JOIN ( 
         SELECT funds.startup_id, MAX(funds.id) as maxid 
         FROM funds 
         GROUP BY funds.startup_id 
     ) f ON funds.id = f.maxid 
         AND funds.startup_id = f.startup_id
     where fund_type="Series B")
```

The thing is the Inner Join is already done between the 2 tables in laravel and while concatenating I have to include the sql part after 'IN' in form of Eloquent query. please help.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to get this query with `Eloquent`.